# Loop through each column in ListView(Vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, webforms

How do I loop through each column to get its value/data in a listview?
I tried:

```
      For each item as ListViewItem in lsvCurrent.Items
      Next
```

But I'm getting syntax error of "Value of type ListViewDataItem cannot be converted to ListViewItem.

Hoping someone could direct me how to properly loop through each row and each column in a listview in VB.net

Thank you!

Comment: A _ListViewDataItem_ is used to represent an Item in the WEB control ListView.  (ASP.NET) The ListViewItem is for desktop apps. (WinForms)

Comment: I see. But how do I loop through each row and each column in list view using listviewdataitem?

Comment: You don't loop over the ListViewDataItem but over the underlyng DataSource assigned to the ListView

Comment: I have added more relevant tags to your question. Please specify all relevant information. There are multiple ListView controls so you need to make it clear which you are using. You're trying to use code for one when your control is a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the comments, yes, listview item is the correct choice here.

So, say this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In LVHotels.Items

        ' get row index 
        Dim MyRowIndex As Integer = lvItem.DisplayIndex

        ' get database primary key assuming you using datakeys
        Dim DataBasePK As Integer = LVHotels.DataKeys(MyRowIndex).Item("ID")

        ' Get value of a label on this row

        Dim lblHotelName As Label = lvItem.FindControl("HotelName")
        Debug.Print($"Row {MyRowIndex}, Hotel = {lblHotelName.Text} Database PK = {DataBasePK}")


    Next


End Sub
```

So, in above we see/get the row index. We get the hidden database PK id (this you VERY much want to use). to use datakeys, then use this in the listview define (markup).

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVHotels" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      etc. etc. etc.
```

So, when I run the above code, I get/see this:

output:

```
Row 0, Hotel = Batman's Cave Database PK = 16
Row 1, Hotel = Inns of Banff Database PK = 5
Row 2, Hotel = Mary's Motel Database PK = 7
Row 3, Hotel = Mountain View Hotel Database PK = 1
Row 4, Hotel = Ramada Lodge Database PK = 2
Row 5, Hotel = Sandman Inn Database PK = 3
Row 6, Hotel = Super 8 Database PK = 4
Row 7, Hotel = Swiss Village Database PK = 6
```

So, yes, in fact ListViewItem is the correct object type to use here.

You can as above shows get the row index, then get the database PK (this value is hidden to the user - by using datakeys), and then of course to pluck, get values from each row, you use .findcontrol as per above.

In above, the hotel name was a label in the markup, and was this:

```
  <td>
     <asp:Label ID="HotelName" runat="server" 
       Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' />
  </td>
```

You can't use ListViewDataitem, since that ONLY exists during the data binding process - ONCE the listview been data bound, then the listviewData items go out of scope.

So, ListViewDataItem is VERY nice, and can be used say "during" the Row data bind event. And it gives you FULL use of the WHOLE data row - not limited to JUST columns in the listview display.

However, as noted, the instant the data binding process is complete, then data item and listviewdataItem are null and out of scope - and can't be used "after" the data bind process has completed.

```
 DataItem = only avaiable during binding - data row, not contorls
 ListViewItem = always avaialble - is the listview row - not data row
```

so the database "row" information is not persisted in a Gridview, or a listview (or in fact any of the data bound controls such as repeater, listview, gridview etc.).

## Edit: Above shows how to get all rows, what about columns?

So, the above loop shows how to iterate over each row.

What about each column for each row?

There not really a column collection for each row.

This means to get columns for each row, you have to in general use find control for each of the controls.

so, say you have several columns like this:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="onerow" runat="server">
            <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
```

Well, then you have to use that ListViewRow . findcontrol.

So,  in the example loop code, then to get hotel name, (a label), then as per above code posted, then this:

```
 Dim lblHotelName As Label = lvItem.FindControl("HotelName")
 -- thus lblHotelName.Text <--- this gets hotel name column
```

So, for each column value, it takes a bit of extra code.

you could in theory loop each of (all of) the controls in that one list view row. However, you would have to test/check each control type, and it would be quite a bit of code. So, use .findcontrol to get the columns from the listview.